# How to perform nationwide Twitter Stream searches with Tweepy?

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

***What's the best way to use the Twitter Stream API with Python to collect tweets in a large area?***

I'm interested in geolocation, particularly the nationwide collection of tweets in North America. I'm currently using Python and Tweepy to dump tweets from the Twitter streaming API into a MongoDB database.

I'm currently using the API's location-filter to pull tweets within a boundary box, and then I further filter to only store tweets with coordinates. I've found that if my boundary box is large enough, I run into a Python connection error:

```
raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
```

I've made the bounding box smaller (I've successfully tried NYC and NYC + New England), but it seemms like the error returns with a large enough bounding box. I've also tried threading with the intention of running multiple StreamListeners concurrently, but I don't think the API allows this (I'm getting 420 errors), or at least not in the manner that I'm attempting.

I'm using Tweepy to set up a custom `StreamListener` class:

```
class MyListener(StreamListener):
    """Custom StreamListener for streaming data."""

    # def __init__(self):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            db = pymongo.MongoClient(config.db_uri).twitter
            col = db.tweets

            decoded_json = json.loads(data)
            geo = str(decoded_json['coordinates'])
            user = decoded_json['user']['screen_name']

            if geo != "None":
                col.insert(decoded_json)
                print("Geolocated tweet saved from user %s" % user)
            else: print("No geo data from user %s" % user)
            return True         

        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
            time.sleep(5)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
```

This is what my `Thread` class looks like:

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, streamFilter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.streamFilter = streamFilter

    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.name)
        #twitter_stream.filter(locations=self.streamFilter)
        Stream(auth, MyListener()).filter(locations=self.streamFilter)
```

And `main`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    auth = OAuthHandler(config.consumer_key, config.consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(config.access_token, config.access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())

    # Bounding boxes:
    northeast = [-78.44,40.88,-66.97,47.64]
    texas = [-107.31,25.68,-93.25,36.7]
    california = [-124.63,32.44,-113.47,42.2]


    northeastThread = myThread(1,"ne-thread", northeast)
    texasThread = myThread(2,"texas-thread", texas)
    caliThread = myThread(3,"cali-thread", california)

    northeastThread.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    texasThread.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    caliThread.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing bad or unusual about getting a `ProtocolError`. Connections do break from time to time. You should catch this error in your code and simply restart the stream. All will be good.

BTW, I noticed you are interrogating the `geo` field which has been deprecated. The field you want is `coordinates`. You might also find `places` useful.

(The Twitter API docs say multiple streaming connections are not allowed.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems twitter allocates one block of tweets when you try to search a keyword in a big geo (let's say country or city). I think this can be overcome by running multiple streams of program concurrently, but as separate programs.